# What mean this function in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, methods, oop

I saw a function declared like this below.

```
<?php 
public function getFirstName():string
{
    return $this->firstName();    
}
```

why this **:string** is used and when I should use this.

Comment: String is return type of the getFirstName() function

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7 introduce a new feature to define return type of function called as "return type declaration".

You can define return type of function by define return type after colon.

if strict type is enabled by declare as " declare(strict_types = 1);". then the function with return type declaration are bounded with return value.

```
<?php
   declare(strict_types = 1);
   function inttypedeclaration(int $val): int {
      return $val;
   }
   print(returnIntValue(4));
?>
```

> The output of above function is 4

```
<?php
   declare(strict_types = 1);
   function inttypedeclaration(int $val): int {
      return $value + 'string';
   }
   print(returnIntValue(5));
?>
```

The above function throw an error

> Return value of inttypedeclaration() must be of the type integer,
> string returned..

Answer (score 0):

Your function `public function getFirstName():string` using :string it is giving us a hint that the function can only return the string value only.
If it tries to return non-string value like integer then it must throw error. 
Thanks

Vibhore

Answer (score 0):

":string" to process the returned data of this function. It is required to return a string type. All other data than the string is returned in this function to be treated as an error